# Qual diferença de Array/array, Object/object, etc?

Tags: javascript, característica-linguagem

Estou bem no começo do meu estudo em programação e não estou entendi bem esses tipos com a primeira letra maiúscula em JavaScript, como `Number`, `Array`, `Object`, etc.

```
let a = Array
let b = [1, 2]
let c = Object
let d = {a: 1, b: 2}
```

Porque os tipos com letra maiúscula são funções?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A linguagem JavaScript disponibiliza algumas variávies (palavras reservadas) com funcionalidade pré-defenida. Neste caso da tua pergunta estamos a falar de tipos primitivos, ou seja os blocos construtores da linguagem. Esses tipos são: `Boolean`, `Number`, `String`, `Symbol`, `Object`.

Quando perguntas *"Porque os tipos com letra maiúscula são funções?"* - a resposta é: porque a linguagem é feita assim.

Podes usar esses tipos como funções:

```
Boolean(123) // dá true
Boolean(0) // dá false
```

Mas também podes usar como construtores para obter objetos, e aí já tens de ver o resultado como um objeto que pode expôr propriedades:

```
const zero = new Boolean(0);
console.log(!!zero); // dá true porque um objeto valida como true quando convertido em Boolean
console.log(zero.valueOf()); // dá false, o valor booleano de "0"
```

Comment: Era esse segundo código que não estava entendendo, com esse operador new.

Comment: @thar93 ótimo que a minha resposta ajudou a perceber melhor.

Answer (score 0):

O JavaScript é uma linguagem *[case sensitive](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case-sensitive)*, ou seja, diferencia letras maiúsculas e minúsculas (tal como Java, PHP entre outras).

Algumas palavras, como `Array` e `Object` são palavras de funções internas da linguagem ([veja palavras reservadas](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp)), e começam com letras maiúsculas pela própria sintaxe da linguagem. Logo a palavra `array` pode ser apenas uma variável qualquer — da mesma forma que `object`.

Você até pode usar palavras reservadas como variáveis, mas isso nunca deve ser feito porque você irá alterar o tipo e a função delas, e isso irá causar erro se você precisar usar a função nativa relacionada à palavra:

```js
let Number = "texto"; // Number é uma string qualquer
console.log(Number);
let numero = Number("3"); // aqui a função Number() dá erro pq você declarou como string antes
console.log(numero);
```

No exemplo acima eu subverti a função `Number` transformando ela numa string, resultando em erro na linha `let numero = Number("3");`.

No exemplo abaixo, eu não mexi na palavra `Number` (declarei a primeira variável com "n" minúsculo) e a função nativa não foi alterada e funcionou corretamente:

```js
let number = "texto"; // number é uma string qualquer
console.log(number);
let numero = Number("3");
console.log(numero);
```

Resumindo, o problema não é bem se uma palavra começa com letra maiúscula ou minúscula, é em você saber a sintaxe da linguagem e diferenciar quando uma representa uma função, propriedade ou método (seja começando com letra maiúscula ou minúscula), e quando uma palavra pode ser apenas uma palavra qualquer que pode ser usada como uma variável qualquer.